# Android DownloadManager not know where the file downloads

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import

After two days of tests we were able to partially work.
I downloaded the file, but I have no idea where to store it.
I tried to download a picture and the picture appears in the folder /all_downloads

I do not know how to store it in /sdcard/update.

```
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.app.DownloadManager.Query;
import android.app.DownloadManager.Request;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.File;

public class Upgrade extends ActionBarActivity {
    private long enqueue;
    private DownloadManager dm;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upgrade);

        BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
                    long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(
                            DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
                    Query query = new Query();
                    query.setFilterById(enqueue);
                    Cursor c = dm.query(query);
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        int columnIndex = c
                                .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                        if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c
                                .getInt(columnIndex)) {


                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
                DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Request request = new Request(
                Uri.parse("http://android.vrt.ro/tv-update/v1.apk"));
        enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);


    }

    public void showDownload(View view) {

        Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                .setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/download/v1.apk"),
                        "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        startActivity(promptInstall);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/updates", "update.apk");
```

> Added in API level 9

```
public DownloadManager.Request setDestinationInExternalPublicDir (String dirType, String subPath)
```

> Set the local destination for the downloaded file to a path within the
>   public external storage directory (as returned by
>   `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String))`.
>
> The downloaded file is not scanned by MediaScanner. But it can be made
>   scannable by calling `allowScanningByMediaScanner()`.
>
> Parameters dirType    the directory type to pass to
>   `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory`(String)` subPath  the path within the
>   external directory, including the destination filename Returns this
>   object Throws IllegalStateException   If the external storage directory
>   cannot be found or created.

You can also use this version

```
String updatePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Updates" + File.separator + "update.apk";
request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(new File(updatePath)))
```

Comment: where you need to put this line? Can you show me? are beginner and try to put yourself on the line but I appear red in studio android
Thanks for your speed. Thank you

Comment: put it before this line "enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);"

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what you said, go.
What should I do to not download 2 times? or if there is not to download apk file? How to call function to know what I should look. I do not have much knowledge but I wish to learn. Thanks again

Comment: you should check if enqueue != 0... then the donwload is already in progress... make sure once it completes to set it to 0, so you can know that it is no longer downloading. You can simply check if it exists by doing something like that  boolean isApkPresent = new File(filePath).exists();